# Как запретить определенный девайс на сайте?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Суть вопроса, как заблокировать определенную модель телефона на сайте?
Постоянно идет спам. По IP не вариант - динамический.
UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-A310F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.210 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: ну так и эти данные поменяет, не борись с ветряной мельницей, забей

Comment: Навряд ли поменяет)

Comment: спам идёт от программы, которая передаёт такой UserAgent, а не от телефона определённой модели. И поменять UserAgent так же легко, как 2 байта переслать

Comment: Нет там спама от программы. Человека знаю лично кто шлет.

Comment: ну так скажи ему лично в лицо https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357983/how-to-block-some-of-http-user-agent-using-php

Comment: я не спрашиваю что и как кому сказать, вопрос есть сверху